# Deleting a file created with a SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, root, file-permissions, permissions, deleting

I am trying to delete a file created with a `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement into the `/tmp` directory

The file belongs to the `mysql` user (who doesn't have a login shell).

I have administrative privileges on the database (i.e. I can login into mysql as the root user), but I don't have the root password of the machine onto which the service runs.

Is there a way to delete the file myself, or do I need to relay the task to the administrator of that machine each time?

thanks,

Silvio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system user doesn't own the file in `tmp` or is at least member of the same group as the file belongs to, you can't delete, edit or move it.